# Comment/Uncomment specific format in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse how do I comment & un-comment Java code in specific format shown below?

I am not able to find proper answer for that even on Stack Overflow?

```
/*
 * public class HelloWorld {
 *
 *   public static void main (String[] args) {
 *       // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
 *      System.out.println("Hello, World");
 *   }
 *
 *}
 */
```

Comment: Its Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: Do you want to make block of code in line when you comment it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in shortcut to comment in this exact way. The most similar way would be to select the code you want commented and use

Ctrl + Shift + /

Which block comments, but does not add the extra line of asterisks to the left.

Comment: can you try :  first select code to be comment and then ctrl + Shift + / , save the code by ctrl + s , you will reproduce that format , now , I wont be able to un-comment it same way .

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse the shortcut to comment out is Ctrl+Shift+c. Just make sure you select the lines that you need to comment out before using the short cut.

Comment: That adds inline comment marking (`//...`), not the format requested in the OP.

Comment: There is no built-in shortcut for that way.

Comment: First select code to be comment and then ctrl + Shift + / , save the code by ctrl + s , you will reproduce that format , now , I wont be able to un-comment it same way!!